# Mounting a floating breakfast bar

Tags: mounting, uk

I'm making a breakfast bar out of a piece of spare worktop. It is 110cm long and cut to 50cm deep, with a width of 28mm. It will be fixed in a corner of two masonry walls, and the current plan is to attach it using lengths of 70mmx70mm angle iron (30 or 40cm length on the short side and 80cm length on the long side). I was going to use M8x80mm bolts to attach the angle iron to the wall (something like [these](https://www.screwfix.com/p/easyfix-bright-zinc-plated-carbon-steel-concrete-bolts-m8-x-80mm-10-pack/6293p#product_additional_details_container)) and 1/2" screws to attach the worktop to the angle iron (like [these](https://www.screwfix.com/p/easydrive-pz-wafer-self-tapping-screws-8ga-x-1-2-100-pack/8979H?kpid=8979H&cm_mmc=Google-_-Datafeed-_-Screws%2C%20Nails%20and%20Fixings?kpid=KINASEKPID&cm_mmc=Google-_-TOKEN1-_-TOKEN2&gad_source=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgLWk3YezhAMVUJRQBh3r8Ap3EAQYBSABEgKdA_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#product_additional_details_container)).

For accessibility reasons, we cannot have any support legs, but my wife also wants it to be mounted strongly enough for a person (let's say 100kg) to stand on the free corner without it collapsing ('just in case'). Is this a reasonable requirement? Have I over- or under-specced this? Thanks for any tips!

**Edit**: Several comments suggest that this will collapse. I don't expect the angle iron to pull away from the wall or the worktop to snap, so I guess that means the worktop pulling away from the angle iron? Would 3/4" screws work better, in that case?

We can't have an angle bracket with a 45-degree support on the free end (we need clearance under that end, hence the 'floating' breakfast bar), but we could put a 35cm L-shaped bracket like [this](https://www.diy.com/departments/mastershelf-herkules-bracket-40x35cm/5060846243813_BQ.prd?alt=true) if that would do it? We don't *expect* a ~100kg load, but want to future proof it for someone doing something foolish (like sitting/standing on the free end).

Comment: Should not take a 100kg to collapse that.  Can you have shelf brackets/angles or similar to add support for that end?

Comment: @Ecnerwal The angle irons would be 70mmx70mm (and ~6mm thick) with *lengths* of 30cm/80cm along the wall.

Comment: OK, yeah, that will break. Needs a bracket or lunar gravity to hold 100kg.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! By break/collapse I guess you mean that the worktop would pull way from the angle iron?

Comment: You will need supports under it or above it.  For people standing on it, I would suggest steel cables up to the ceiling.  Will give the person something to hold on to.  Angle iron or similar at ~45 degrees from the front to the back wall will work also, better under the work bench than above, if you cannot use legs to the floor.